# Is there any way to avoid having to import from a @types file in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm building a project with TypeScript but I'm still getting used to it. I'm not sure that I'm going about it the best way. On the client, I'm maintaining a types files located in a @types dir off of the root src dir.

One of the things that seems off to me is having to import the definitions from said type file.

```
import { MultiSelectFilter } from '../../../@types';
```

I guess I need to make the client more domain driven so this doesn't feel as unnatural. I'm just curious if there is a way to avoid the need for this?

Thanks.

#### edit:

tsconfig.ts

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "declaration": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["global.d.ts", "next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a global module. Use the extension `.d.ts` in a file at your root src.
Then, every typescript file will be able to access the types declared there without importing them:

```
// src/global.d.ts

declare type MultiSelectFilter: any
```

Once done you can use all declared types in `global.d.ts` without importing them:

```
// src/index.ts

// import { MultiSelectFilter } from '../../../@types';  // You dont need this import anymore!
const multiSelectFilter: MultiSelectFilter; // This WORKS!
```

It's generally recomended to use file based modules and not polluting the global namespace.

Comment: I edited my question to include my tsconfig. It isn't able to locate the types.

Comment: Having said that, if it is recommended to use file based modules, I guess I should go back to a types file for now and worry about making my client side more domain driven later.

Comment: Are you having any problem creating the `d.ts` file? Regarding your last coment, its recomended creating a `global.d.ts` for entities that are pure global. But you can create `module1.d.ts` in `src/module1` and it will only affect that path. So you can create the types that module1 will use there.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by having problems creating the d.ts file? It seems to be fine and VS Code is recommending that I import '../../global'

Comment: You dont have to import `global.d.ts` anywhere. Once created, its automatically detected by typescript. So you can write `let multiSelectFilter: MultiSelectFilter ` on any file without importing it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210115/discussion-between-chance-and-rashomon).